# Match filenames without extensions and move them to new directory if match is found - Bash

Tags: bash

There are two directories one containing XML and one containing binaries (jpg and mp4). I need the script to check both directories and if a *.jpg, a *.mp4 and a *.xml matches exactly on a filename - then the script needs to move all the matching files with matching names to a new directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Origin
xmlDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump'
binaryDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/binaryDump'
Dest01='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination'
TopLevel='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2'


cd $TopLevel
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.xml" -or -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.mp4"`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then 
    baseName=${file%\.*}
    if [ $baseName=${file%\.*} ] ; then 
        echo $baseName
        echo "success"
        mv -v $baseName $Dest01
    fi
fi 
done
```

But the problem I am running into is mv the files to the destination directory. so at the moment the error I get is that it tries to mv the files without extension to the destination directory.

mv: rename ./xmlDump/test_002 to /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination/test_002: No such file or directory
mv: rename ./xmlDump/test_001 to /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination/test_001: No such file or directory
mv: rename ./binaryDump/test_003 to /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination/test_003: No such file or directory

How do you get the bash script to only move the files with a matching filename (excluding extension) to the destination directory?

Comment: does the destination directory exist?

Comment: Yes the destination directory exists - I tried with "mv -v $file $Dest01" and all the files were moved into the destination directory

Comment: But you try to call mv on the filename with the extension stripped. There may not be such file and I guess this is what causes the error. So if you have try.jpg You try to execute `mv -v try ~/dest` and there is no file temp.

Comment: Yes correct - but I am not sure how to get all the matching filenames into a variable and then move these files into the destination directory.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking... doesn't the variable $file iterate over all the files matching the given constraints?

Comment: Sorry I might have complicated the question - the variable $file only contains files with certain extensions (*.mp4, *.xml, *.jpg) that the script finds recursively in the directories. I then would like the script to find cases where there is a match such as test.xml, test.mp4 and test.jpg and the move this bundle of files to a new directory. Sorry if my question was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the question in the original response, so here's a better edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Origin
xmlDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump'
binaryDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/binaryDump'
Dest01='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination'
TopLevel='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2'

#don't cd into the directory, search in it from the root directory instead
#cd $TopLevel
for file in `find $TopLevel -type f -name "*.xml" -or -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.mp4"`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then 
    file_name=$(basename $file)
    basename=${file_name%\.*}
    if [ -f "$binaryDump/$basename.jpg" -a -f "$xmlDump/$basename.xml" -a -f "$binaryDump/$basename.mp4" ]
    then 
        echo "success, basename: $basename, full file name: $file"
        to_delete="$file $to_delete"
        cp -v $file $Dest01
    fi
fi 
done

rm -v $to_delete
```

This is not the most versatile solution, but it should work in this case

Comment: If I do that it will move all files with the extensions *.mp4, *.jpg and *.xml into the destination directory - regardless of whether these files have matching filenames. The script should only move files called *.xml, *.mp4, *.jpg if they have matching filenames.

Comment: It only moves the XML files into the destination directory - but otherwise everything is right

Comment: it assumes a flat folder structure. do you have nested folders in the binaryDump dir?

Comment: Sorry - just realised what you asked me and no all mp4 and jpg are in binaryDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/binaryDump'

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, can you give that a shot

Comment: Still only moves the .xml files into the destination directory

Comment: /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump/test_003.xml
success, basename: test_003, full file name: /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump/test_003.xml
/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump/test_003.xml -> /Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination/test_003.xml              so the XML gets moved

Comment: ok I figured it out, there's a flaw in the logic: because you are using `mv` as soon as you find a "good" file, you are removing that file from future validation for the other 2 types of files. So when you find test_003.xml, you move it, hence you aren't able to confirm if test_003.xml exists when you are looking at test_003.jpg. I'm updating the answer with the fix

Answer (score 1):

So if I get what your idea you want only to copy file that exist with all extensions i.e. there is a A.jpg, A.mp4 AND A.xml. if that is your question here is how you can do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Origin
xmlDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/xmlDump'
binaryDump='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2/binaryDump'
Dest01='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST1/destination'
TopLevel='/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/TEST2'


cd $TopLevel
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.xml" -or -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.mp4"`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then 
    baseName=${file%\.*}
    if [ -a "$basename\.jpg" ] && [ -a "$basename\.xml" ] && [ -a "$basename\.mp4" ] ; then 
        echo $baseName
        echo "success"
        mv -v $file $Dest01
    fi
fi 
done
```

Comment: Correct - yes that is what I want the script to do. - Let me try your example out. Thank you.

Comment: The way I have written it, the move will only happen if all three files reside in the same folder. If you want to achieve something else, the script will have to be modified.

Comment: Thank you for this - I will try and tweak it since the .mp4 and the .jpg files will be in a different directory than the .xml